# Can't Access MAMP remotely

Tags: mamp

I have installed MAMP on a server and I'm trying to run files on it from other computers on the network. I've changed the port to 8888 and I've tried connecting with the internal and external ip addresses. There is no firewall. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the beta MAMP for WINDOWS which had some bugs. I switched to XAMPP, changed the port, and have had no issues!